# 2d vectors (vector subscript out of range)

Tags: c++, vector, 2d

I have written code to parse strings into a 2d vector called input. I want to put the first index's string into a vector that stores nodes with lhs and rhs. The first index of of every vector should be in lhs and every other character into the rhs. I get a vector subscript out of range with the code that loops 3 or more times. What am I doing wrong?

```
struct finalNode
{
    string rhs;
    string lhs;
    bool isTerm;

};

void fillGramRules()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
    {
        finalNode fNode;

        //attempts to copy first position 0 of every array to string lhs of     fnode, this crashes the program
        fNode.lhs = input[i][0].symbol;
        newNode.isTerm = input[i][0].isTerminal;
        for (int j = 1; j < input[i].size()-1; j++)
        {
            newNode.rhs.append(input[i][j].symbol);
            newNode.isTerm = input[i][j].isTerminal;
        }
        gramRules.push_back(fNode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Apparently, `input[[i]` is empty for some value of `i`.

Answer (score 1):

If input[i] is empty, then trying to access input[i][0] will cause a crash, so you probably want to check that first.

```
if(!input[i].empty()) {
    fNode.lhs = input[i][0].symbol;
    newNode.isTerm = input[i][0].isTerminal;
}
```